# Convolution and space-time Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

I have a general function $u(x,y,z,t)$. Then,

(1) what would be the space-time Fourier transform of $$G \star \frac{\partial^n u}{ \partial t^n }$$

and

(2) would the relation $$G \star \frac{\partial^n u}{ \partial t^n } =  \frac{\partial^n (G \star u)}{ \partial t^n }$$ hold true?

Here, note that (a) the symbol $\star$ represents convolution in space and (b) $G$ is a function of $(x,y,z)$ only (i.e. it does not depend on time).

Comment: Is the convolution in space only?

Comment: Tryss, thanks! yes, the convolution is in space only. I clarified it by editing the question.

Comment: What seems to be the challenge?  Do you know the convolution theorem?  And do you know the relationship between the FT of a function and that of its derivative?

Comment: @Dr.MV , to me, the challenge appears to be two folds. First, does the usual convolution theorem holds true even for space-time Fourier transforms? IF it does, then I can write the Fourier transform as F(G).[(iW)^n].F(u). In this case, F(G) = ?? Second, can I bring the G* inside the derivative even for the space-time transform? For the usual cases where only space or time is involved, yes, I can. Since I am not a Fourier transform expert, the space-time aspect of the transform is worrying me. It would be nice if you can confirm the above.